# Check the file changed using chef-client

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have the following scenario:

Suppose i have configuration **file A** which is copied during sever provisioning at any location example: "**/temp**" using chef recipes and after someday someone modified 2-3 parameter in the configuration file.

Is this possible to find out such files and rollback to old one  or copied A file again to the **/temp** location.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `file A` is managed by your chef recipe then running `chef-client` again will correct any drift in the file to whatever is in your chef recipe for it's contents.

For example if you have:

```
file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
  content 'foo'
  action :create
end
```

Then someone changes the content of `/tmp/fileA.txt` to `bar` then on your next chef-client run it will update the content to `foo` again.

Or if you are pulling in a file from the cookbook like:

```
cookbook_file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
  source 'fileA.txt'
  action :create
end
```

Then someone updates `/tmp/fileA.txt` the next time you run `chef-client` it will pull the file from your cookbook again.

Or if you want to use a locally stored file you can do that as well:

```
remote_file '/tmp/fileA.txt' do
  source 'file:///tmp/fileAsource.txt'
  action :create
end
```

Here the `file:///tmp/fileAsource.txt` syntax is referring to the local filesystem file `/tmp/fileAsource.txt`. If the content changes from whats in the source file it will update `/tmp/fileA.txt`

Comment: Thanks for response one have question here, Is chef-client required any recipe to monitor the file.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. Im not 100% sure what you were asking in the comment. If the recipe doesn't have a resource for the file, it wont monitor the file. It will only manage things you tell it to.

Comment: thanks, instead of content can i use file name with path, to compare it?

Comment: This is just an example, however you'd normally manage a file works fine. Whether that is `remote_file` `cookbook_file` `template` or whatever.

Comment: I am new to chef, can you please provide me an example to compare two file like /tmp/fileA.txt with /root/fileA.txt and if someone change the file /tmp/fileA.txt then chef-client replace it again with /root/fileA.txt..this will be very helpful to me

Comment: @PawanSharma I added some more examples for you

Comment: Is it possible to track only 3-4 lines in a file, if some changes those 3-4. chef-client will revert it back. the first method which i have mention is checking the whole content is a file.